# Defining rigorously, the intuition of Limits

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

This is an attempt to define rigorously from scratch, the following intuitive definition of limits:

> $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}=L$ means that $f(x)$ can be made *arbitrarily close* to $L$ by making $x$ be *sufficiently close* to $c$.

Given the above definition of limits, we can say that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}=L$ means that for every $x \ne c$  in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)\ne L$ there exists some $x_0$  in the domain of $f$ that is closer to $c$ than $x$ is and for which $f(x_0)$ is closer to $L$ than $f(x)$ is.

**Making $f(x)$ be arbitrarily close to $L$:**

If for some $x$ you give me, I can give you some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is closer to $L$ than $f(x)$ is then we will say that $f(x)$ *can* be made closer to $L$ at that particular $x$ value.
If I can do this for every $x\ne c$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)\ne L$ then we will say that $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily close to *L*. The relationship between $x$ and its corresponding $x_0$ can be stated as follows: $$|f(x)-L|>|f(x_0)-L|; f(x)\ne0$$

**Making $x$ be sufficiently close to $c$:**

Now that we have made the first condition true, we need $x_0$ to be closer to $c$ than $x$ is. We don't want an $x_0$ that is farther away from $c$ than $x$ is. If $f(x_0)$ does get $f$ closer to $L$ but $x_0$ is farther away from $c$ than $x$ is and we can't find any $x_0$ which:

1. Gets $f(x)$ closer to $L$ and
2. Is itself closer to $c$ than $x$ is.

Then we would say that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}$ does not exist. The relationship between $x$ and $x_0$ can be stated as follows: $$|x-c|>|x_0-c|;x\ne c$$

**Reason for specifying that $x\ne c$ and $f(x)\ne L$:**

If $x$ is exactly at $c$ then it is impossible to make $x$ be any closer to $c$ than it already is. The distance between $x$ and $c$ is $0$ and it can't be made any smaller. Similarly, $f(x)$ can't get any closer to $L$ if $f(x)=L$.

**Putting it all together:**

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}f(x)}=L$ means that for every $x\ne c$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)\ne L$, there exists an $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ such that:
$$|x-c|>|x_0-c|$$ and $$|f(x)-L|>|f(x_0)-L|$$

Is my reasoning correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please, specify what has changed with respect to your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742377/an-alternate-definition-of-limit/3742391#3742391

Comment: This is wrong. There is no reason to avoid the possibility $f(x) = L$: maybe $f$ is a constant function. For the same reason (constant functions) your other strict inequalities are not good.  The meaning of a limit is *first* say how close you want $f$-values to be to $L$ (within some $\varepsilon$) and *second* you can specify a whole punctured interval around $a$ where *all* $f$-values are that close (withing $\varepsilon$). It is not a game of finding *some* closer value, because such an idea doesn't avoid the possibility of farther values too.

Comment: @Miguel In my previous question, I only stated my result and didn't show the work. This time I have provided both and am asking for some feedback for my work.

Comment: @KCd Is the intuitive definition I used incorrect?

Comment: A little mistake, In the finally is $|f(x)-L|...$ not  $|f(x)-c|...$

Comment: @DavidK Could you explain with a specific example?

Comment: the argument fails when $c$ is an isolated point

Comment: Why are you doing this? What exactly about existing definitions of limits do you not like?

Comment: Have you *tried* to compare your property to the actual definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, specifically show a function $f$, point $a$, and value $L$ fitting your property also satisfies the conventional definition of a limit?  If you do then you'll find at some point you will get stuck.

Comment: Your approach of taking the intuition behind the idea and formalizing it in your own terms is really admirable - absolutely the best way to approach mathematics in my opinion.  Although wrong in this case, as David K's answer demonstrates (especially his function $g$), by approaching it this way you will end up with a much better understanding than if you had just accepted the standard definition without question.

Comment: @user762914 It's not that I don't like the existing definition of limits but rather that it doesn't fit with my intuition of what a limit *is*. I am doing this because I need to see how my intuition connects with the rigorous definition, if at all.

Comment: @KCd Is the following assessment correct?   Let $f(x)=10$, the set of $x$ values satisfying $x\ne c$ and  $f(x)\ne 10$ is an empty set. The set of $x_0$ values for this empty set will also be any empty set. Using my definition of limits, you would conclude that the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist at any $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: The definition of a limit provides no mechanism to compute limits, but only to check if a choice is correct or not: the proposed limit $L$ is in the definition. If you want to show a limit does not exist you'd need to show (if using the definition) that for *every* $L$ the definition of $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ is not satisfied. Your insistence on using $f(x) \not= L$ is strange to me; yes, I know you are trying to align your intuition with the real definition, but there is *no* reason to avoid the possibility of $f(x) = L$ when $x \not= c$. The graph of $y=f(x)$ can cross $y=L$ many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intuitive definition that you quoted at the beginning is correct but is too subtle regarding some very important concerns.

It is not enough that there exists some $x_0$ closer to $c$ such that $f(x_0)$ is closer to $L.$ You need there to be an $x_0$ such that *every* $x_1$ closer to $c$ has $f(x_1)$ as close as *some arbitrarily small distance* from $L$. Moreover, you need to be able to *repeat* this feat no matter how small the arbitrarily small distance becomes.

Your interpretation misses the "every", "arbitrary", and "repeat" parts.

For example, consider the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{x} & x \neq 0,\\0 & x = 0. \end{cases}$$
This function crosses the $x$ axis infinitely many times between $-\frac1\pi$ and $\frac1\pi.$
By your definition, $L = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0,$ because someone can pick any $x$ they like, where $f(x) \neq 0,$ but then there will always be infinitely many $x$-axis crossings between $x$ and $0,$ and you can always find an $x_0$ near one of those $x$-axis crossings such that $f(x_0) = \frac12 f(x),$ which is closer to $L.$

But actually $f(x)$ has no limit at all as $x\to 0.$ It oscillates infinitely many times ever larger and larger as you approach $x=0.$

What your definition misses in this case is that one $x_0$ is not enough. Sure, we can always get $f(x_0)$ closer to zero by choosing $x_0$ carefully, but there are many other $x$-values even closer to $0$ that give much worse values when you apply $f$ to them.

Now consider a second function,
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}x-1 & x < 0,\\ x+1 & x \geq 0. \end{cases}$$

Now again your definition says
$L = \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0,$
because given any $x,$ we can simply set $x_0 = \frac12 x,$ and it is guaranteed that
$g(x_0)$ will be closer to $L$ than $g(x)$ is.

What your definition missed in this case is that although we can always make $g(x_0)$ be *closer,* we cannot make it be *arbitrarily close* to $L = 0.$
The closest we can get is $1$ unit above or below $0.$

---

I like to think of limits using an adversarial game as an analogy.

The rules of the game are that I choose a number, $x_1,$ and say that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $x_1$ is some number, $L.$
Then my opponent gets to challenge me by specifying a distance from $L.$
I have to respond with a distance from $x_1.$
My opponent then gets to choose any number $x_2$ within my chosen distance from $x_1.$
And that means they get to choose *any* such number, not necessarily one that I would like them to pick.
If $f(x_2)$ is closer to $L$ than the distance my opponent named, I win.
Otherwise I lose.

The limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to x_1$ is $L$ if my position in this game is a winning position, that is, there is no way my opponent can challenge me with a distance, no matter how small, that lets my opponent pick an $x_2$ with $f(x_2)$ farther than that distance from $L.$
No matter how small a distance they choose, I always have a winning response.

What are the conditions under which I win? I need to have a function $f$ and a number $x_1$ such that by judiciously choosing neighborhoods around $x_1$ (a neighborhood being all numbers within some chosen distance of $x_1$), I can shrink the range of $f(x)$ on that entire neighborhood down to an arbitrarily small interval around $L.$

The usual epsilon-delta definition of limits is essentially this game translated into mathematical logic, where $\epsilon$ is the distance my opponent chooses and $\delta$ is the distance I choose.

---

Note that I have only dealt with functions on all real numbers here.
There are some additional points that come up when the domain is only a proper subset of the real numbers, as implied by a comment below.

I also want to reiterate the point someone made in a comment under the question, that you do more mathematics by trying to reinterpret the definitions and getting it wrong than you do if you don't even try.
So you have a good question. Don't stop trying.

Comment: The definition is also incorrect for the case $f (x) = \{(c, L) \}$